# Asus X205TA microSD HC card not recognised

Tags: laptop, drivers, micro-sd-card, memory-card, asus-laptop

I have got this laptop: [X205TA](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ASUS-X205TA-11-6-Inch-Laptop-Notebook/dp/B015EL2BNS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1457017297&sr=8-1&keywords=asus%20x205ta) and bought this SD card: [SanDisk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B010NE3QHQ?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00)
and my laptop does not recognize this card. I have tried to download a card reader driver, but there seems to be no such driver. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does it not recognize it, or does it not mount it? When inserted, does it show in Drive Management at all?

Comment: Nope. Nothing happens when I insert it

Comment: In Device Manager is the card reader shown? This device uses standard drivers from Microsoft, in Windows 10 manufacturers tend to only publish drivers if they are not available from Windows Update. Also, in Drive Management does it show an unrecognized volume, or nothing (not in Computer)?

Comment: In device manger (under storage controllers) I get an additional 'SD Storage Class Controller' entry when I insert the card. But when I insert it I then have two entries for the 'SD Storage Class Controller'. I am on Windows 8

Comment: and it does not appear in disk management at all

Comment: Fixed it. I was looking at the wrong thing in the device manager. There was this yellow exclamation mark saying the driver is not install for the sd card. So it found the driver on its own.

Comment: So it was missing the driver for the card, or the reader? Don't want to turn this into a discussion but it seems odd that Windows 10 wouldn't load the driver automatically when the card was inserted, unless you were not connected to the Internet the first time you inserted the card (Win 10 doesn't keep a large repository if drivers locally)

Comment: Was missing a driver for the reader. That point about the Internet: may very well be the case!

Comment: Gotcha... since that was one of my comments, I will change it to an answer, please mark it as acceptable if you agree.

Comment: For future readers: for my friends computer, on which also audio, trackpad and keyboard failed, this was solved by Vogel612's answer in [No Sound device recognized after Win10 Fall Creators's Update](https://superuser.com/questions/1313760/no-sound-device-recognized-after-win10-fall-creatorss-update/1507446#1507446).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Device Manager is the card reader shown? This device uses standard drivers from Microsoft, in Windows 8 and newer manufacturers tend to only publish drivers if they are not available from Windows Update. Check Device Manager to see that the card reader has proper drivers installed, if not or a yellow or red indicator is next to the device, right click the device and select Update Driver and then allow it to search Windows Update for the appropriate driver which should then install itself. Note that an active Internet connection is required when doing this.