# No Sound device recognized after Win10 Fall Creators's Update

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-10-v1709

After the Fall Creator's Update for Windows 10 my Asus Notebook X205TA does not recognize any sound devices anymore.

Windows Troubleshooting in the first run installed a Realtek Codec, but that seems to not have fixed the underlying problem.
The next run then recommends restarting to finish driver installations (as if I didn't do that)...
Any subsequent runs just result in the troubleshooting not finding any solutions to the problem.

In the device manager, there is only the Realtek Codec under Sound and Multimedia devices.

In the system devices, the Driver for "Low Power Low Power Engine Audio - Host Bridge - 0F28" seems to have a problem. Unfortunately no newer drivers are available through Windows update.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the latest chipset drivers are not working correctly.

In [this german forum](https://www.drwindows.de/probleme-patches-windows-update/137300-kein-audioausgabegeraet-installiert.html) a user recommends downgrading the chipset drivers to version V112, available from the [Official ASUS Driver download support site](https://www.asus.com/de/Laptops/ASUS_EeeBook_X205TA/HelpDesk_Download/)

When installing them, a warning about there being a newer version of the driver installed will appear.
Install the driver and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of search engines, after fixing a friend's X205TAW-FD0061TS:

This happened again for the November 2019 update (to 1909), and likely also for the other updates (which my friend skipped). And for her, for both the April 2018 and the November 2019 update, it also affected the internal SD card reader, the trackpad and even the internal keyboard.

[Like @Vogel612 described](https://superuser.com/questions/1313760/no-sound-device-recognized-after-win10-fall-creatorss-update/1313761#1313761) this can be fixed using the Intel chipset drivers for Windows 10, 32 bits, which today are still at version V112, October 27th 2015. It seems the very same drivers are present in `C:\eSupport\eDriver\Software\Chipset\Intel\SOCPackage_X205TA\Win10_32_112` on the machine itself, but I just used the download instead. (It also seems one can remove that folder, which frees 734 MB of its 32 GB disk space, though that breaks the "Repair" option for drivers that have been installed from that folder. Not a problem, I'd say.)

As for the internal SD card: it seems that it is not recognized after a restart *during* the update. When Windows update needed some extra temporary disk space, selecting the internal SD card was a bad choice, as after the update-in-progress restarted the computer, it showed me a black screen with a dialog saying:

> Error
>
> Please insert the external storage media and press OK

Selecting OK needed an external USB keyboard or mouse again, and then just showed the same error, endlessly. (Choosing Cancel aborted the update; no damage done.)

Even more: a next try using an USB disk failed the very same way, until I *first* ejected the SD card, *before downloading/starting the update*. Maybe the USB disk was assigned an unexpected drive letter while the SD card was not recognized after the restart? I don't know.

For the next update, I'm going to try [the Media creation tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install) instead. But I'm quite sure we'll again need the Intel chipset drivers after that.